# How to assign view only published dashboards in Apache SUperset

Tags: apache-superset

I know that the Published/Draft function on dashboards is not made to have private dashboards, but i would like to limit the access to the Draft dashboards as they can access by the Url. I have tried to look for the rights but i have not seen anything. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

'View' Role that I have created in Superset. This only gives read access to Dashboards and nothing else. Only dashboards those are published will be listed from Dashboard Menu. But, still if a user has URL of the dashboard, he/she can access.

```
[can list on DashboardModelView, can list on CssTemplateModelView, can list on CssTemplateAsyncModelView, can list on DashboardModelViewAsync, can get on Datasource, can explore on Superset, can fave dashboards by username on Superset, can recent activity on Superset, can fave dashboards on Superset, can csv on Superset, can request access on Superset, can dashboard on Superset, can favstar on Superset, can profile on Superset, can explore json on Superset, can csrf token on Superset, menu access on Dashboards, all datasource access on all_datasource_access]
```

Answer (score 2):

In Superset version 1.2.0 they add feature `DASHBOARD_RBAC` in `FEATURE_FLAGS`.
Set `DASHBOARD_RBAC = true` and set access roles in dashboard properties. This is exact what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [@Dharam's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3473833/dharam) older [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63133424/3599233), having superset version 1.5.0, for me the following Roles worked:

```
[can read on SavedQuery, can read on CssTemplate, can read on Chart, can read on Dashboard, can read on DashboardFilterStateRestApi, can read on DashboardPermalinkRestApi, can get on Datasource, can favstar on Superset, can explore json on Superset, can explore on Superset, can csv on Superset, can request access on Superset, can fave dashboards by username on Superset, can recent activity on Superset, can fave dashboards on Superset, can dashboard on Superset, can profile on Superset, menu access on Dashboards, all datasource access on all_datasource_access]
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution to this, was to create a new user and assign them the default Alpha Role. This user will only view published dashboards. Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: This only limit the list of dashboards, but they can access by the url. What I need is to block the access to "Draft" dasbhoards